# C++ pass derived struct to method expecting the super struct

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to create a menu library for arduino with C++ and OOP.

I have a struct called:

```
struct MenuItem {
    int position;
    String name;

    MenuItem(int position, String name) : position(position), name(name) { };
};
```

And I have a derived struct called:

```
struct SpecificMenuItem : MenuItem {
    int count;

    SpecificMenuItem(int position, String name, int count) : MenuItem(position, name) , count(count) { };
};
```

How can I pass an array of the `SpecificMenuItem` structs to a method that expects an array of `MenuItem`? The idea here is that all the derived structs from `MenuItem` should have `position` and `name`, so that a simple list can be rendered out with the following method from the `Menu` class:

```
Menu::Menu() {
}

void Menu::setMenuItems(MenuItem *menuItems) {
  this->mMenuItems = menuItems;
}
void Menu::render(void) {
    for (int j = 0; j < this->mMenuItemSize; j++) {
        Serial.println(this->mMenuItems[j].name);
    }
}
```

The header file for specific_menu.h:

```
class SpecificMenu : public Menu {
    struct SpecificMenuItem mSpecificMenuItem[2] = {
      {1, "Name", 3},
      {2, "Name 2", 4}
    };
  public:
    SpecificMenu();
};
```

The cpp file for specific_menu.cpp:

```
SpecificMenu::SpecificMenu() : Menu() {
  this->setMenuItems(this->mSpecificMenuItem);
  this->setMenuItemsSize(2);
}
```

The issue right now is that having the extra `count` member in the `SpecificMenuItem` struct is causing the program to crash, however the program runs fine if I remove the `count` member, but I think this is just a fluke that it works. Would love to get some pointers on how to get the above to work.

Cheers!

Comment: You can't get the above to work; when you expect to pass an array of MenuItems it really has to be an array of MenuItems. There's no polymorphism for arrays of objects in C++.

Comment: You can't; inheritance is not compatible with arrays in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an array of `SpecificMenuItem` to a method waiting for an array of `MenuItem`, even if `SpecificMenuItem` inherits from `MenuItem`.

One possible way would be to remove the `setMenuItems` methods and makes use of polymorphism to access the size and the items of the menu:

```
class Menu {
protected:
    virtual size_t size () const = 0;
    virtual MenuItem& operator[] (size_t) = 0;
};

class SpecificMenu : public Menu {
    SpecificMenuItem mSpecificMenuItem[2] = {
        {1, "Name", 3},
        {2, "Name 2", 4}
    };
protected:
    virtual size_t size () const { return 2; }
    virtual const MenuItem& at (size_t i) const {
        return mSpecificMenuItem[i];
    }
public:
    SpecificMenu();
};
```

And then use these method in `Menu::render`:

```
void Menu::render(void) {
    for (int j = 0; j < this->size(); j++) {
        Serial.println(this->at(j).name);
    }
}
```

This is making your `Menu` acts as a (abstract) container of "`MenuItem&`".

Comment: Thank you for getting me thinking in OOP again, I did not realize the issues of passing arrays of derived class to a method that expects an array of base class.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better declare something like:

```
typedef std::list<MenuItem *> MenuItemArray;
```

Then you can access you base classes by pointer.

```
void 
Menu::setMenuItems(const MenuItemArray& menuItems) 
{
  this->mMenuItems = menuItems;
}

void 
Menu::render(void) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < this->mMenuItems.size(); j++) {
        Serial.println(this->mMenuItems[j]->name);
    }
}
```

Afterward, if you need to access a `SpecificMenuItem` element:

```
...
SpecificMenuItem *specificItem = dynamic_cast<SpecificMenuItem *>(mMenuItems[i]);
if (specificItem) {
   ...
}
```

The solution you initialy wrote rather looks like a C solution, not  C++ IMHO.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you can't put different structs/classes in same array, as they have different sizes. Consider making array of pointers, that point to objects of base class, as they can point to derived as well. Like

```
typedef MenuItem * MenuItemPtr;
typedef MenuItemPtr * MenuItemPtrArray;
MenuItemPtrArray myArr= new MenuItemPtr[2];
myArr[1] = new MenuItem(/*...*/);
myArr[2] = new SpecificMenuItem(/*....*/);
```

Of course, you can use `std::list` or other collectionas @Holt suggested in his answer, and it would be better solution. But I suppose you don't have it as you write for arduino, which has no stl